# Getting mouse coordinates on a World Space RectTransform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First post so let me know if theres any ediquette rules or otherwise I'm breaking.

**Details of this are:**

- This is all based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ajD1GDbEzA&t=508s) for a non world space UI inventory.
- I'm working on a 3d game with a first person perspective at the moment.
- I'm trying to make a grid system that can be accessed anywhere in the world space.
- There's multiple grids, they can be detected via onpointerenter

**The problem**

- Currently this script only works when inputs are coming from a 0,0 degree angles (so the camera is facing a specific angle). Anything else and the results are inaccurate
- I think this is due to the script this is based on not being designed for 3d use. The mouseposition coordinates can get very high/low and thats one obvious cause to the inaccurate grid results

**The code**

```
public Vector2Int GetTileGridPosition (Vector2 mousePosition)
{   
    var pos = mousePosition; 
    Vector3 output = Vector2.zero;

    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(this.rectTransform,pos,cam,out output);  
         
    positionOnTheGrid.x = (output.x - ((rectTransform.position.x ) ));
    positionOnTheGrid.y = rectTransform.position.y - output.y;  
    tileGridPosition.x = (int)Mathf.Abs((positionOnTheGrid.x/tileSizeWidth)); 
    tileGridPosition.y = (int)(positionOnTheGrid.y/tileSizeHeight); 

    return tileGridPosition;
}
```

**Example of method call**

```
Debug.Log("This tha" + selectedItemGrid.GetTileGridPosition(Input.mousePosition));
```

**Example of the script that detects grid via mouse enter**

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        Cursor.visible = true;
        inventoryController = FindObjectOfType(typeof(InventoryController)) as InventoryController;
        itemGrid = GetComponent<ItemGrid>();
    }


  public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    { 
        inventoryController.selectedItemGrid = itemGrid;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        inventoryController.selectedItemGrid = null;
    }
```

**Example of a full script (attached to camera) calling on mouse position in grid**

```
{
 
        if (selectedItemGrid == null) { return;}
         Debug.Log("Testing position " + selectedItemGrid.GetTileGridPosition(Input.mousePosition));
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                  {
                  Vector2Int tileGridPosition = selectedItemGrid.GetTileGridPosition(Input.mousePosition);
                   
                    if (itemModel == null)
                    { 
                      itemModel = selectedItemGrid.PickUpItem( tileGridPosition.x, tileGridPosition.y); 

                    }
                    else{
                        
                     bool complete = selectedItemGrid.PlaceItem(itemModel, tileGridPosition.x, tileGridPosition.y);
                     if (complete)
                     {
                       itemModel = null; 
                     }
                    }
                  }
   

    }
```

Comment: why `Mathf.Abs` and casting to `(int)` wouldn't you rather want to know if you are outside of the rects bounds (negative values) and also round to int to avoid float inaccuracy issues?

Comment: @derHugo I should have attached this in the OP, I'm getting the grid depending on the mouse entering it, and there may be several grids. Theres a script called on mouse enter that detects this/selects a grid for interaction. Updated the OP to include the scripts. 
Yes

Comment: What nonce voted this down?! Perfectly good question. +1.

Comment: Appreciate you're basing this off a tutorial but I wonder if there's an easier way, like using raycasting to compare the ray cast hit to an array of grid locations? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html. Are you using mouse enter because you have a UI showing the grid? If so, is that important for you, e.g. the UI highlights the selection? Is the above code on the 3D game objects or your UI?

Comment: I'll try and see if I can try the raycasting and using the hit location from that to inform the grid location
Re the second question; yes I am. A grid atm is comprised of an image/gameobject that stores amongst other things the GetTileGridPosition script & the mouse enter script.